# How to create class constructeur that accept array of values?

Tags: java, android, arrays, constructor, opengl-es

I develop on Android platform and something bothered me , there is no GLFloat , GLInt , etc etc....

It forced me to create buffer everytime and that sucks.

I want to create a class for each type but when I initialize them I like to do it the same way that the original :

```
GLFloat vertex = new GLFloat() { 0.0f ,0.0f ,0.0f,
                   1.0f,1.0f,1.0f};
```

How I should write constructor to make that happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public GLFloat(Float ... values) {
  for ( Float value : values ) {
    // your code
  }
}

... 


GLFloat vertex = new GLFloat( 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f );
```

This is called [var args](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). Or the argument list with variable length.

Comment: i can't make the initialization like an array ?

Comment: no, you can't. but for you it is just syntax difference. Who cares where you pass params - in curly brackets or in round ones?

Comment: lol yes , i know it doesn't change but it was also curiosity. thanks